# What Is Causing My Code to Loop? Wrongly Instantiating a Class?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on a program that grabs the Iframe from a link and then proceeds to download the episode. For some reason when I call the method to actually download the file, which is located in another class, it causes an infinite loop and produces more instances of the class which causes the program to constantly create new JFrames. What could be causing this? Am I not instantiating the class properly?

Line 21 is where it calls the other class, thus causing the loop.

Class 1:

```
package com.trentmenard;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import java.io.IOException;

class WebsiteScraper {
    private String URL;
    private Document websiteConnection;
    private String episodeName;
    private String iFrameLink;
    private String URLDownloadLink;

    //FOR DEBUG PURPOSES:
    private String directDownloadLink = "https://st1x.cdnfile.info/user1342/1f1b04321e51fac1c1d1c23a1de4f7f0/" +
            "EP.1.mp4?token=qV-3haWjcomPzXJVAeBtdg&expires=1579170124&id=113345&title=(orginalP - mp4) Sword+Art+" +
            "Online%3A+Alicization+%28Dub%29+Episode+1";

    WebsiteScraper(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
        //connectToURL(URL);
        new DownloadEpisode(directDownloadLink, episodeName); //LOOP STARTS HERE
    }
    private void connectToURL(String URL){
        if(URL.startsWith("https://st1x.cdnfile.info/")){
            getDirectDownloadLink();
        }
        else{
            try {
                websiteConnection = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                System.out.println("Connection Successfully Established to: " + URL);

                if(URL.equalsIgnoreCase("https://swordartonlineepisode.com/sword-art-online-season-3-episode" +
                        "-1-english-dubbed-watch-online/")){
                    episodeName = "Sword Art Online Season 3 Episode 1 English Dubbed";
                    getIFrameLink();
                }
                else if((URL).equalsIgnoreCase(iFrameLink)) {
                    getDownloadLink();
                }
                else if(URL.equalsIgnoreCase(URLDownloadLink)){
                    getDirectDownloadLink();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to Establish Connection to:" + URL);
            }
        }
    }

    String getNextEpisodeURL(){
        String nextEpisodeURL = websiteConnection.getElementsByClass("button SAO").get(1).attr("href");
        System.out.println("Found Next Episode URL: " + nextEpisodeURL);
        return nextEpisodeURL;
    }

    String getNextEpisodeName(){
        Element h2 = websiteConnection.selectFirst("h2");
        String nextEpisodeName = h2.text();
        System.out.println("Found Next Episode URL: " + nextEpisodeName);
        //getIFrameLink();
        return nextEpisodeName;
    }

    private void getIFrameLink(){
        Element iFrame = websiteConnection.selectFirst("iframe");
        iFrameLink = iFrame.attr("src");
        System.out.println("Found iFrame Link: " + iFrameLink + " for: " + episodeName);
        connectToURL(iFrameLink);
    }


    private void getDownloadLink() {
        Element hiddenID = websiteConnection.getElementById("id");
        String hiddenIDValue = hiddenID.attr("value");
        URLDownloadLink = "https://www.vidstreaming.io/download?id=" + hiddenIDValue;
        System.out.println("Found Download Link Using ID Value (" + hiddenIDValue + "): " + URLDownloadLink);
        connectToURL(URLDownloadLink);
    }

    private void getDirectDownloadLink(){
        if(URL.equalsIgnoreCase(URLDownloadLink)) {
            new DownloadEpisode(URL, episodeName);
        }
        else if(URL.startsWith("https://st1x.cdnfile.info/")){
            new DownloadEpisode(URL, episodeName);
        }
        else{
            Element downloadClass = websiteConnection.getElementsContainingOwnText("Download (orginalP - mp4)").first();
            directDownloadLink = downloadClass.attr("href");
            System.out.println("Found Direct Download Link: " + directDownloadLink);
            new DownloadEpisode(directDownloadLink, episodeName);
        }
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
package com.trentmenard;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

class DownloadEpisode{

    private String URL;
    private static DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    public DownloadEpisode(String URL, String episodeName) {
        System.out.println("[Debug:] Instance called!");
        this.URL = URL;

        float Percent = 0;
        String downloadProgress = "0.00";

        JFrame progressFrame = new JFrame();
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

        progressBar.setSize(100, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        progressFrame.setTitle("Downloading: " + episodeName + " - " + Percent + "%");
        progressFrame.add(progressBar);
        progressFrame.setVisible(true);
        progressFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        progressFrame.setSize(575, 100);
        progressFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel percentComplete = new JLabel(downloadProgress + "% complete.");
        progressFrame.add(percentComplete);

        WebsiteScraper websiteScraper = new WebsiteScraper(URL);
        String nextEpisodeURl = websiteScraper.getNextEpisodeURL();
        String nextEpisodeName = websiteScraper.getNextEpisodeName();

        File createFile = new File(episodeName + ".mp4");
        if(createFile.exists() && !createFile.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("File Already Exists! Moving Onto Next URL.");
            new DownloadEpisode(nextEpisodeURl, nextEpisodeName);
        }
        else{
            try {
                java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                System.out.println("Connection Successfully Established!");
                System.out.println("Downloading File: " + episodeName);

                int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
                float totalDataRead = 0;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int i = 0;

                java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(episodeName + ".mp4");
                java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);

                while ((i = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                    totalDataRead = totalDataRead + i;
                    bout.write(data, 0, i);
                    Percent = (totalDataRead * 100) / filesize;
                    decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
                    downloadProgress = decimalFormat.format(Percent);

                    progressFrame.setTitle("Downloading: " + episodeName);
                    progressBar.setValue((int) Percent);
                    percentComplete.setText(downloadProgress);
                }
                bout.close();
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection Failed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1c5A.png

Comment: Both of your constructors call each other unconditionally, so this is unbounded recursion and you'll get a stack overflow. The `WebsiteScraper` constructor has the line `new DownloadEpisode(directDownloadLink, episodeName);` and the `DownloadEpisode` constructor has the line `WebsiteScraper websiteScraper = new WebsiteScraper(URL);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebsiteScraper` is creating a `DownloadEpisode` which is creating a `WebsiteScraper` in the constructor which is calling `DownloadEpisode` and so on.

If you have an ordering issue around creating classes then have a look at the Factory pattern.